# text blurry when using label component on AS3

Tags: actionscript, text, label, blurry

I have a problem when dealing with label component on AS3. The text was blurry on one application but not on the other. I have used the same code when dealing with the label component except the one with clear text used scaling to scale the label component and not being used on the other.

Is there because the scale that cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its scaling but it seems Z-Index causes the issue.
I fixed it by removing my x and z values (you may also consider removing y). In my case layout was relative with no layers, so these values were useless.